# Firestore get all documents (contain subcollections) from a root collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an android app with java and i use firestore database i have a collections called user location who is structured like in photo :

> db->RootCollection->document->subCollection->document->subColections->object

my problem is that when a user change his location or a new user come in a location who is alredy exist (other user have same location) it create a new document (like in "oran, algerie"). I wanted to use `option.merge` when I add a new user and update the documents but the problem is that I cant retrieve all documents of the root collection I used the normal way:

```
db.("Users Locations").get()...
```

It return null. I tried to use the `collectionGroup` method:

```
mDb.collectionGroup("User Locations").get()...
```

It returns already null
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, you need to use a CollectionGroup query on the `User List` collections:

```
mDb.collectionGroup("User List").get()...
```

As a matter of fact, there is no documents in the `Users Locations` collection: As we can see in your screenshot, these "documents" are displayed with an italic font in the Firebase console: this is because these documents are only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection but they are not "genuine" documents.

Comment: i want to retrieve them to let only one exemplaire of each location how can i do

Comment: You cannot easily do something like that. You should probably change your data model.

Comment: i'm working on a dating app and what i want to do is showing each user only users who are in same city i dont know if use the correct method what i'm doing i create a collection who contain the cities name and add each user on their respective city(collection) then i want to retrieve to show them if any idea dont hesitate.